# not returning value

Tags: c#, datatable

actually my code shows an error "not all code paths return a value"

```
public DataTable Do_Insert_Update_Delete(string Proc_name, params object[] arg)
{
    if (Proc_name == "Vehicle_Booked_Info")
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Vehicle_Booked_Info", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.Add(" @Today_Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(arg[0].ToString());
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
}
```

even I am putting here `return dt`

If I use this out of  if clause it shows error that is

> dt not exists in current context

How to overcome this?

Comment: return New Datatable() or atleast add return null statnement outside the if block

Comment: I would suggest to invert the `if` case to reduce nesting, so `if (Proc_name != "Ve...") return null; /* same as before */`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **returning inside the `if` statement** and compiler can't determine whether the condition will be met. You need to return something outside the `if` block or in the else block, since your method is suppose to return an object of type `DataTable`, now what if the `Proc_name` is something other than `"Vehicle_Booked_Info"`, you method will not return anything. So change your method,  like:

```
public DataTable Do_Insert_Update_Delete(string Proc_name, params object[] arg)
{
    if (Proc_name == "Vehicle_Booked_Info")
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Vehicle_Booked_Info", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.Add(" @Today_Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(arg[0].ToString());
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
  else
    { 
     return null; //Or some default value.
    }       
}
```

Comment: @Default, yes, or an exception can be raised. Depends on the requirement

Comment: yes indeed. Just `throw`ing it out there :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public DataTable Do_Insert_Update_Delete(string Proc_name, params object[] arg)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    if (Proc_name == "Vehicle_Booked_Info")
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Vehicle_Booked_Info", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.Add(" @Today_Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value =       Convert.ToDateTime(arg[0].ToString());
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        sda.Fill(dt);
    }       
        return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `return null;` just before end of your method:

```
    }       
    return null;
}
```

`else` phrase is not necessary here.

Compiler shows error, because the method does not return a value when `if` statement condition is not met.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad code practice..

change it to following

```
public DataTable Do_Insert_Update_Delete(string Proc_name, params object[] arg)
{
    if (Proc_name == "Vehicle_Booked_Info")
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Vehicle_Booked_Info", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.Add(" @Today_Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(arg[0].ToString());
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        return dt;

    }       

    return new DataTable();// or return null


}
```